# JAX-WS web service using a JAX-RPC (AXIS1) client

Tags: java, jax-ws, jax-rpc

I am new to web service. Can anyone please tell me if JAX-WS web service can be accessed using a JAX-RPC (AXIS1) generated client stub?

Answer (score 3):

no.  "jax-rpc" is so named because it only supports the "rpc/encoded" xml format.  jax-ws webservices only support the "document/literal" format, which is not compatible.